# How would one strip text before and after a certain html tag

Tags: php, html, text, strip, strip-tags

Basically I want to take something like:

```
textheretextheretexthere
<table>
<tr><td>heres some stuff</td><td>and some morestuff</td></tr>
</table>
moretextheremoretexthere
```

and remove all the texthere and moretext here just leaving the table

Comment: if "texthere" and "moretexthere" are not HTML nodes then it will be extremely difficult to handle.

Comment: Define certain.  How certain?

Your example is very generic and depends on the situation.

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find `<table>` position with `strpos` and then use `substr` to remove the text to this point.and then the same for `</table>`

```
$string = 'textheretextheretexthere<table><tr><td>heres some stuff</td><td>and some morestuff</td></tr></table>moretextheremoretexthere';

$table_pos = strpos($string,'<table>');
$string = substr($string,$table_pos);
//Your string now is <table><tr><td>heres some stuff</td><td>and some morestuff</td></tr></table>moretextheremoretexthere

$endtable_pos = strpos($string,'</table>')+8;//added 8 so i wont exclude </table>
$clean_string = substr($string,0,$endtable_pos);
//Your string now is <table><tr><td>heres some stuff</td><td>and some morestuff</td></tr></table>
```

Of course this is not perfect at all,i know but you got the hint,you can work on improving it and maybe end up with a function that helps you solve your problem.

- [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)
- [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';    

echo strip_tags($text);
echo "\n";

// Allow <p> and <a>
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');
?>
```

Comment: that would remove the tags yes, i am looking to remove any and all text before and after an html block that has been stripped, sorry i should have been more clear

Answer (score -1):

This is would be the easiest way.

http://yelotofu.com/2008/08/jquery-outerhtml/